Task.WaitAll()がすべてのタスクが終了する前にブロック解除される
C# WPF .NET 8.0で期待通りにTask.WaitAll()が動きません。
やりたいこと
定周期タスクの中で以下の動きをしています。

ある条件Aを満たしたときにメソッドCを非同期で実行開始します。このときCにCancellationTokenを渡します
ある条件Bを満たしたときに非同期で以下の順序で処理を起動します。　　
2-1. CancellationTokenのCancelメソッドを呼ぶ
2-2. Task.WaitAllでCの終了を待つ。
2-3. C終了後の処理を行う

期待動作
メソッドCの処理が完了したあとに、2-3.の処理が行われる。
発生現象
2-3.の処理が完了したあとにCの処理が完了する
再現コード
WPFアプリを新規作成してMainWindow.xaml.csに以下を記述します。
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfAndTask
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    static private object _lock = new();
    static int num = 0;
    static Timer timer2;
    static Timer timer1;
    static CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    static List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    private const int threadNum = 200;
    static List<(string, Action<string, bool, CancellationToken>)> _actions = new List<(string, Action<string, bool, CancellationToken>)>();

    private static void timerproc1(object obj)
    {
      var list = _actions.FindAll(x => x.Item1 == "test");
      foreach (var action in list)
      {
        var task = Task.Run(() => {
          action.Item2(action.Item1, true, _cts.Token);
        });
        taskList.Add(task);
      }

    }
    private static void timerproc2(object state)
    {
      Task.Run(async () => {
        Debug.WriteLine("All tasks started.");
        _cts.Cancel();

        await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());
        Debug.WriteLine($"num = {num}");
      });

    }
    static void TaskMain()
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i++)
      {
        _actions.Add(new("test", AsyncMethod));
      }

      timer1 = new Timer(timerproc1, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.Zero);
      timer2 = new Timer(timerproc2, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.Zero);
      while (true)
      {
        Task.Delay(100);
      }
    }

    static async void AsyncMethod(string key, bool value, CancellationToken token)
    {
      try
      {
        await Task.Delay(100000, token); // 仮の非同期処理
        Debug.WriteLine($"AsyncMethod1 completed with argument: {key} {value}");
      }
      catch
      {
        lock (_lock)
        {
          num++;
        }
        if (num == threadNum)
        {
          Debug.WriteLine($"AsyncMethod1 Canceled. {key} = {num}");
        }
        return;
      }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      TaskMain();
    }
  }
}


サンプルはコンソールアプリのようですが、問題が再現できなうのはそのためでは？　コンソールアプリでは SynchronizationContext が WPF のような　GUI アプリとは違います。

async / await と WaitAll (現在のタスクが完了するまで呼び出し元のスレッドを待機させる同期メソッド) を混ぜているようですが、そこが問題なのでは？ 試しに Task.WaitAll に代えて await Task.WhenAll を使ってみたらどうなりますか？

おっしゃるとおりWPFアプリのMainWindow.xaml.csのコンストラクタで上記のコードを実行すると問題が再現しました。

await Task.WhenAllでも問題は再現しました。

ケアレスミスのようです。
timerproc1メソッドでは以下のようにタスクを開始しています。
var task = Task.Run(() => {
  action.Item2(action.Item1, true, _cts.Token);
});

このaction.Item2はAsyncMethodであり、そのシグネチャはasync voidとなっていますので、action.Item2の実行は瞬時（正確にはawaitにさしかかったタイミング）で完了するような動きとなります。
今回のコードで正しく動かしたいなら以下の点を書き換えてください。

AsyncMethodのシグネチャをasync voidからasync Taskに書き換える。
_actionsをList<(string, Func<string, bool, CancellationToken, Task>)>に書き換える
実行部分を Task.Run(async () => { await action.Item2(action.Item1, true, _cts.Token); }); に書き換える。

asyncやawaitを使う場合、async voidにした箇所が出た時点で、「待たない部分ができた」と考えましょう。
